# Local lighthouse has much different score than web.dev lighthouse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lighthouse

While running my create-react-app website on web.dev to see the lighthouse results, I noticed that they weren't exactly good. [image: Screenshot of web.dev results]

However, when I run lighthouse on my system with these settings:

[image: Local Lighthouse settings]

I get better results:

[image: Screenshot of local lighthouse results]

Note that I am running local lighthouse in incognito.

Is it IndexedDB that is making my results better? If so, how can I stop IndexedDB from doing so?

Also, just as a side note (this doesn't really need to be answered) are these results okay? It's a PWA so everything would be cached afterwards. Thanks!

Comment: If items are stored in IndexedDB then you need to go to the application tab in developer tools & clear them there. I thought they would get cleared by default but perhaps they don't when running locally. Could you open the application tab and see if clearing that changes your score. Bear in mind that Lighthouse is a tool more than anything so as long as you address as many items under "opportunities" and "diagnostics" that you can in a reasonable time scale you will be fine. Also it depends on whether this page needs to rank in Google / is part of a conversion process as to whether it matters.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I don't visit this site often. When I cleared IndexedDB, it brought the performance stat closer to the one on web.dev (76 local vs 71 web.dev) but the best practices didn't change which was a bit confusing. However, you're right when you say that it is simply a tool. Thank you for responding to this question! @GrahamRitchie